# mysqldump on remote server to local machine: error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'10.213.213.11'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running the command line as an administrator and trying to perform a MySQLdump to grab a backup of a table on a remote server. I would just go to the server and grab a back up there but I have over 100 different servers to grab a backup from. Here is what I have:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47>mysqldump -P3306  -h172.30.0.40 -u root -p apha polldistribution >test.sql
Enter password: **********
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'10.213.213.11' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

I have tried to grant all on my local machine as well as the remote machine. I have also logged into the remote database using the exact same password, and it can access fine it just wont work when performing a dump. And I tried to migrate through MySQL workbench but I get the same error message when prompted for a password.

Once I am able to get through one server I can make a program to loop through them all. Its just a problem connecting. Hopefully someone has some insight on this. All I really need is to be able to get my backup. Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: Did you give authorization user@% ?

Comment: 'root'@'10.213.213.11' is not in mysql.user. add one and it would be fine.

Comment: Lwin Htoo Ko that did the trick! Thanks a bunch.